# How to ignore object attribute temporary while serialization in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, serialization

I'am using the spring framework to create a rest server. I've got a controller class and could ask for an itempattern object by id or get all objects. With spring i serialize the object to JSON, using `@ResponseBody` and `@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`.

My controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/itempatterns")
public class ItempatternController {
    /**
     * injected resource service interface,
     * loads objects from database
     */
    private IItempatternResource resource;

    /**
     * GET one itempattern by the three identifier,
     * URL: /rest/itempatterns/:id
     *
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Itempattern getTirepatternById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return resource.getById(id);
    }

    /**
     * GET all itempatterns,
     * URL: /rest/itempatterns
     *
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody List<Itempattern> getAllTirepatterns() {
        return resource.getAll();
    }

}
```

From resource i could receive an itempattern object, that looks like that:

```
public class Itempattern implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6168853991825655795L;

    @JsonProperty("itemtype")
    private Itemtype itemtype;

    @JsonProperty("pattern")
    private String patternXML;

    public Itempattern() {
        super();
    }

    public Itempattern(Itemtype itemtype, String patternXML) {
        super();
        this.itemtype = itemtype;
        this.patternXML = patternXML;
    }

    //...getter and setter
}
```

The problem is, that the attribute `patternXML` is a very long string and sometimes i want to load all itempatterns with all attributes and sometimes the attribute `patternXML` should be ignored while serialization (to save network resources). For example i want to fill a select list and don't want to load all objects with their `patternXML` attributes (maybe load it later on click).

**Is there a possibility to ignore an attribute in some cases temporary while serialization with `@ResponseBody`?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should the ignore happen in one request? Means `List<Itempattern>` may contain `Itempattern` that contains serialized `patternXML` and `Itempattern` that contains blank `patternXML`?

Comment: The ignore should happen on request but, i would use two methods: One to get a list with `Itempattern` that contains `patternXML` and one to get a list with `Itempattern` that contains blank `patternXML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for Jackson's `@JsonView` feature. With this, you can tell a certain request mapping to produce serialized JSON with chosen set of properties.

**Example**

```
public class View {
    interface Summary {}
}

public class User {

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String firstname;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String lastname;

    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String postalCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @RequestMapping("/messageSummaryOnly")
    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        return messageService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Requests to `/messageSummaryOnly` will produce serialized List in which each `Message` only populated fields are those annotated with `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)`

Reference : https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what i'm searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Fort the conditions when u do not need to load the patternXML , during the conditions make the patternXML value as NULL explicitely in ur program and try to use

```
JSONINCLUDE(INCLUDE.NON_NULL) in your POJO Class
```

so that the value will be null and it will not load the values in ur case.